# ROME RSS: How to get RSS icon

Tags: java, rss, rome

I am trying to write a small RSS Reader. I use ROME in order to get the RSS feeds. This works fine so far. However, I am not able to obtain the RSS icon of the individual feeds. Is there a way to get the icon (e.g. the URL) via ROME or does anybody know an easy way to achieve this through java without ROME?

Comment: Do you mean the favicon.ico of the website?

Comment: @JonLin yes, sorry. I didn't know the name.

Comment: You can't just load http://<hostname>/favicon.ico ?

Comment: @JonLin I will look into that. If you create an answer to my question I am going to accept it, if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The favicon.ico is almost always in the root of the host, for example, for stackoverflow's you can go here: https://stackoverflow.com/favicon.ico and get redirected to the icon. Sometimes, RSS feeds are actually hosted on a different service (like google or feedburner) than the site itself (where all the RSS items are), so you need to access the **`<link>`** element to get the host, then simply access the host's favicon.ico.

Example, over at Crunchy Roll, they use feed burner and the RSS feed looks something like this:

```
<channel>
 <title>Latest in Anime News by Crunchyroll!</title>
 <description>Read about the latest updates on Crunchyroll.com</description>
 <link>http://www.crunchyroll.com/news</link>
```

So if you have a `SyndEntry`,

1. you can call the [getLink() method to access this link](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/java/dev/rome/rome/1.0.0/rome-1.0.0-javadoc.jar!/com/sun/syndication/feed/synd/SyndEntry.html#getLink%28%29), (http://www.crunchyroll.com/news)
2. remove the URI (http://www.crunchyroll.com/)
3. append **favicon.ico** and fetch the icon (http://www.crunchyroll.com/favicon.ico)

This may not always work, although sites really should be putting favicon.ico in their document root, some sites may use a **`<link>`** tag within the page, something like:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="new_category/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
```

To indicate that for a given page, to use this other favicon. This doesn't necessarily mean there isn't a favicon,ico sitting at the document root, just that for this link, to use this icon. So if you want to take the extra steps, you can insert these steps between **1.** and **2.** above:

- Load the link (http://www.crunchyroll.com/news)
- Check for a `<link rel="shortcut icon">` in the header
- Load that and call it a day
- Otherwise continue to step 2